# parameter id_country require prestashop webservice

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I try to create address of prestashop using webservice, but even though I put the id_country to some value it still return `parameter \"id_country\" required`. I am using Prestashop 1.7.8.9.

Body I request using this route `{{webservice_url}}/api/addresses?output_format=JSON`

```
    "address": {
        "id": 9,
        "id_customer": "0",
        "id_manufacturer": "0",
        "id_supplier": "1",
        "id_warehouse": "0",
        "id_country": "8",
        "id_state": "35",
        "alias": "supplier",
        "company": "Fashion",
        "lastname": "supplier",
        "firstname": "supplier",
        "vat_number": "",
        "address1": "767 Fifth Ave.",
        "address2": "",
        "postcode": "10153",
        "city": "New York",
        "other": "",
        "phone": "(212) 336-1440",
        "phone_mobile": "",
        "dni": "",
        "deleted": "0",
        "date_add": "2023-08-11 07:50:47",
        "date_upd": "2023-08-11 07:50:47"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official documentation Prestashop webservices is only able to output JSON, it cannot read JSON inputs.

See: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/webservice/getting-started/

Try rewriting your input in XML and it should work correctly - Data looks good to me.

Comment: how about this https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-send-put-or-post-request-in-json-using-prestashop-webservices/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Can put like this, **DO NOT** put `id` in body it will auto generate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <address>
        <id_customer>0</id_customer>
        <id_manufacturer>0</id_manufacturer>
        <id_supplier>1</id_supplier>
        <id_warehouse>0</id_warehouse>
        <id_country>21</id_country>
        <id_state>35</id_state>
        <alias>supplier</alias>
        <company>Fashion</company>
        <lastname>supplier</lastname>
        <firstname>supplier</firstname>
        <vat_number></vat_number>
        <address1>767 Fifth Ave.</address1>
        <address2></address2>
        <postcode>10153</postcode>
        <city>New York X</city>
        <other></other>
        <phone>(212) 336-1440</phone>
        <phone_mobile></phone_mobile>
        <dni></dni>
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        <date_add>2023-08-14 17:16:38</date_add>
        <date_upd>2023-08-14 17:16:38</date_upd>
    </address>
</prestashop>
```